# ReviewClipse with Zend Studio for Eclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

I've installed the latest ReviewClipse and latest Subeclipse plugin in the latest Zend Studio (6.1.2). I've got a connection to Subversion through Subeclipse but I do not get the Review context menu that the help file suggests: "You may start the review wizard from the context menu of your Subversion shared project under Review - Review Project... It is necessary that your project is shared with Subversion, and the connection to the repository works."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Review Context menu on in the Package Explorer in the Java Perspective.